# Wordpress rewrite url not working on custom template

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

The URL is:

```
mywebsite.com/custom/?var1=random_text
```

and I want

```
mywebsite.com/custom/random_text
```

here's the code in my functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse12965_query_vars' );
function wpse12965_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'var1';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse12065_init' );
function wpse12065_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'custom(/([^/]+))?/?',
        'index.php?pagename=custom&var1=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

But it still returns 404 error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is looking perfect try to add flush_rewrite_rules function.

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse12965_query_vars' );
function wpse12965_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
 $query_vars[] = 'var1';
 return $query_vars;
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse12065_init' );
function wpse12065_init(){
  add_rewrite_rule(
    'custom(/([^/]+))?/?',
    'index.php?pagename=custom&var1=$matches[1]',
    'top'
 );
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```