# Re write rule not working

Tags: wordpress, url-rewrite-module

I have tried to rewrite the URl as http://example.com/book-appointment

For example

I have got a shop data by this url http://example.com/book-appointment/?shop=shop-name.

It should be work as same as url http://example.com/book-appointment/shop-name

I have tried

```
add_rewrite_rule('/book-appointment/([^/]*)', 'index.php?page_id=183&data=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

But it is not working as i write above

The full function, i have written

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^booking-now/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=188&data=$matches[1]', 'top');
  flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Comment: did you flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after adding this rule? If not, go to Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.

Comment: Yes, i have done the flush work as you said. But it is still not working.

Comment: Use a plugin like "Rewrite Rules Inspector" to test the rewrite rules and see what result you get for a particular URL. If the rule is working there, then clear your browser cache, and see this for other potential problems to check for [How do I delete the old Custom Post Type permalink after rewriting the URL to exclude the slug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896666/how-do-i-delete-the-old-custom-post-type-permalink-after-rewriting-the-url-to-ex/45897149#45897149)

Answer (score 0):

Put below code just after your function of add_rewrite_rule :

```
// Add Query var
add_filter('query_vars', 'template_query_vars');
function template_query_vars( $query_vars ){
 $query_vars[] = 'page_id';
 return $query_vars;
}
```

Check with this.
Take the reference of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031990/wordpress-rewrite-url-not-working-on-custom-template/46033560#46033560) you will get more clear idea.

Comment: can you show full function in your question. Please edit it

Comment: Added, Please check the full function.

Comment: did you use this function add_filter('query_vars', 'template_query_vars');